# How to embed custom Google forms in your website?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

Google has recently provided [an API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) to programmatically interact with Google Forms.

I would like to know which script file I need to embed in my website to get that functionality? So far, it seems like you can only use that API in the Google Forms Script Editor?

I stumbled upon [Googletastic](https://github.com/viatropos/googletastic) but I would like to refrain from 3rd party software, since I need this to be as portable as possible (besides, the repository seems unmaintained).

Small hacks are welcome, as long as they are portable and do not add significant security holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to build an Apps Script project and insert the URL into your site. 
To interact with it you will need to make calls to google.script.run wich are located in the iframe generated by Caja. 
I can provided same samples but would be great if you drive me some real scenario.
Best,
Breno

Comment: From what I have learned now, you just need to embed a [Gadget](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/) on your site, no? Not sure why you would need [Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)?

Comment: If you are using Google Sites you can insert a google apps script gadget.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but you still have not explained what Caja is for?

Comment: Sorry Domi, Caja is used to sanitize the code. It will get the html that you wrote and convert to another html sanitized. It need to be done to avoid malicious html. For more information check here (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions). Please check the answear as correct if you agree with the solution :)  Best, Br Araujo

Comment: So what is the difference between using an iFrame and using a Gadget? Any resources on that?

Comment: When you insert a gadget in Google Sites it will generate an iframe. You can use html box and put your own iframe, there is no difference in this way but htmlbox is harder to maintain